# Outward vs Out-swing door

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis

I am curious what the proper use of language is when your talking about doors. Should a door that swings out be called "Out-swing door" or "Outward swing door"? I'm not sure if there is a proper use or a more accepted use of this term.

Comment: Probably *Outward swinging door* is more common.

Answer (score 2):

Neither since swing is not an adjective. Use "swinging" instead along with the word "outward" so "outward swinging door." You can add a hyphen between outward and swinging if you want but it's probably not necessary.

Comment: Thank you there has been some debate here at the office on what we should put on marketing materials.